# Border Line Question for Server Fault?

Tags: discussion

I feel like [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/289688/looking-for-email-hosting) is border line out-of-bounds for Server Fault, but before I become a jerk and flag the first question I've ever "flagged", I thought I'd get other people's opinion. The question is here: [Looking for email hosting](https://serverfault.com/questions/289688/looking-for-email-hosting). I don't see this as a constructive question for the Server Fault community. Rather, it is asking for information that one could find on any number (hundreds) of websites.

Basically, I get the feeling Server Fault isn't the place to look for a webhosting provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering I mod-hammered it close while you were typing this post, I'd say your gut was right on this one.

Also, it was looking for email-hosting, not web-hosting. Slight but significant difference.

Comment: "Slight but significant" - I'm definitely quoting that one at some point in the future. =P

Answer (score 4):

It's not even close. [It's a shopping question, and they aren't allowed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/programming-is-hard-lets-go-shopping.html).

Answer (score 2):

... And by the time I'm done asking this question, and go back to the original question I was pointing to, I see that it has been marked as off-topic and closed by a moderator. Glad I'm not crazy. :)